# Pass a parameter to select case with group by in HQL

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql

I have the following HQL(**The Hibernate Query Language**) query (which is executed on oracle db connection) to retrieve an aggregated sum, based on month

```
select sum(doc._masskg), 
    case when (month(doc._date) = month(:m)) then 'NOW' else 'BEFORE' 
from Document doc 
    where month(doc._date) <= month(:m) 
group by 
    case when (month(doc._date) = month(:m)) then 'NOW' else 'BEFORE' end
```

however, in the runtime I get Oracle exception NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION

if I replace **:m** with **sysdate**, the query works. 
How do I rewrite the query if m: is Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have ended up replacing the parameter with an actual value:

```
String hql = "select sum(doc._masskg), "+
"    case when (month(doc._date) = month(%1$s)) then 'NOW' else 'BEFORE' "+
"from Document doc "+
"    where month(doc._date) <= month(%1$s) "+
"group by "+
"    case when (month(doc._date) = month(%1$s)) then 'NOW' else 'BEFORE' end";

Iterator i = session.createQuery(String.format(HQL, "to_date('09.10.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY')"))
                .iterate();
```